# How to scale the size of a button when the user holds down in Animated React / React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I'm trying to create some code that increases the size of a button when the user holds it down then reverts back to the initial size when released.

I'm relatively new to React/RN and have searched tons of websites to find the result, but can't seem to find anything.

I can't tell whether I should be using PanResponder here or not.  I also tried using Animated.timing, but the timing is hard-coded & not bound to the length of time that the user holds down the button.  I tried Animated.spring, but again that's not bound to length of time that the user holds the button down.

I'll post a quick gif that replicates what I'm trying to go for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzmPF.jpg

Here's what I have so far:

```
this.scaleAnimation = new Animated.value(3)

handlePress = () => {
   Animated.spring(this.scaleAnimation, {
      toValue: 4,
      friction: 2,
      tension: 160
   }).start()
}

render() {
   const pauseStyle = {
       transform: [

            { scale: this.scaleAnimation }

       ]
   }
  return (
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handlePress}>
          <Animated.View style={[ pauseStyle ]}>
              <Ionicons name="md-pause" />
          </Animated.View>
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

Any takes are greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Please find the detailed answer with code snippets.

Add this to constructor of component

```
this.handlePressIn = this.handlePressIn.bind(this);
this.handlePressOut = this.handlePressOut.bind(this);
this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1);
```

This method is for scaling button with animation when button gets pressed

```
handlePressIn() {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
        toValue: 3,
        friction: 3,
        tension: 40
    }).start();
}
```

This method is for resetting button to its initial scale with animation when touch gets released

```
handlePressOut() {
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        friction: 3,
        tension: 40
    }).start();
}
```

Render method

```
render() {
    const animatedStyle = {
        transform: [{ scale: this.animatedValue }]
    }
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
            onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
        >
            <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Press Me</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

You can use different types of animations. Please find the link for reference: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#configuring-animations